# VPN into multiple LAN Subnets

Tags: networking, vpn, subnet, sonicwall

I need to figure out a way to allow access to two LAN subnets on a SonicWall NSA 220 through the built-in SonicWall GlobalVPN server. I've Googled and tried everything I can think of, but nothing has worked. The SonicWall NSA management web interface is also very unorganized; I'm probably missing something simple/obvious.

There are two networks, called `Network A` and `Network B` for simplicity, with two different subnets. A SonicWall NSA 220 is the router/firewall/DHCP Server for `Network A`, which is plugged into the `X2` port. Some other router is the router/firewall/DHCP server for `Network B`. Both of these networks need to be managed through a VPN connection.

I setup the `X3` interface on the SonicWall to have a static IP in the `Network B` subnet and plugged it in. `Network A` and `Network B` should **not** be able to access each other, which appears the be the default configuration. I then configured and enabled VPN.

The SonicWall currently has the `X1` interface setup with a subnet of `192.168.1.0/24` with a DHCP Server enabled, although it is not plugged in. When I VPN into the SonicWall, I get an IP address supplied by the DHCP Server on the X1 interface and I can access `Network A` remotely although I do not have access to `Network B`.

How can I allow access to both `Network A` and `Network B` to VPN clients although keep devices on `Network B` from accessing `Network A` and vice-versa.

Is there some way to create a VPN-only subnet (something like 10.100.0.0/24) on the SonicWall that can access `Network A` and `Network B` without changing the current network configuration or allowing devices on both netorks "see" each other? How would I go about setting this up?

Diagram of the network: (Hopefully this kind of helps)

```
       WAN1                                    WAN2
        |                                       |
[ SonicWall NSA 220 ]-(X3)-----------------[ Router 2 ]
        |                                       |  
       (X2)                               192.168.2.0/24
    10.1.1.0/24
```

Any help would be **greatly** appriciated!

Comment: Is router 2 just a router, or is it also a stateful firewall?

Comment: Router 2 is a stateful firewall, although this shouldn't matter. If I SSH into the SonicWall, I can ping devices on `Network B`. The X3 port on the SonicWall is actually plugged into a switch that Router 2 is also connected to.

Comment: Sure, that's because the Sonicwall has an interface directly in the 2.0/24 network that you can get a direct ARP response from. I'm trying to figure out  how to use a dedicated subnet on the Sonicwall just for GlobalVPN clients... you will need to add a static route onto RT2 for that subnet, I just don't see how to create it just yet. I think a new zone, with a loopback interface in that zone would do it.

Comment: I wish I could full prove this out for you,but I'm fairly certain the answer to your problem will be under the "DHCP over VPN" configuration section under VPN

Comment: I've tried every permutation of settings in the "DHCP over VPN" section. I find it interesting that there is a `VPN` zone pre-configured but it simply shares the `LAN` Subnet (on `X1`, in this case). `Network A` is currently accessible, although `Network B` and  even the `X3` Interface IP are not.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to add network B as a network object and then give the user's group access to it. Still a little unclear here... might be worth a ticket to sonicwall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not that VPN clients could not access the `X3` network, any LAN device on the Sonicwall could not access the `X3` network. Once a NAT entry was created to properally translate the source/destination of the packets destined for the `X3` network everything worked fine. This is also described in a bit more detail in this question: [Sonicwall routing between multiple subnets on multiple interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/452027/sonicwall-routing-between-multiple-subnets-on-multiple-interfaces)