# Sonicwall routing between subnets, firewall rule statistics

Tags: sonicwall, statistics

hello this my first post, i have a problem between two sonicwall
because i want to route two subnets that are connected with a dedicated link, for example with subnet A i can reach the servers but from subnet B i can not reach the clients.
i have made the routing because i can reach the server and i can pull a file from them, so i believe there is no problem with routing

but i have put it firewall rules in both firewall
and this is the output from the statistic from:

LAN A TO LAN B

#

in the other hand the rule in reverse flow it have Rx statistic flowing well, those

14  LAN >   LAN 14 Change priority...   130.0.10.0  X0 Subnet   Any Allow   All None    Enabled Enabled﻿

Access Rule #14 - Traffic Statistics

Rx Bytes:   1000285

Rx Packets: 3744

Tx Bytes:   298962

Tx Packets: 3377

Usage:  451﻿

LAN B TO LAN A

#

LAN >   LAN 13 Change priority...   X0 Subnet   130.0.10.0  Any Allow   All

and this is the statistics, but it didn't work, the Rx bytes are still in 0

Access Rule #13 - Traffic Statistics

Rx Bytes:   0

Rx Packets: 0

Tx Bytes:   41760

Tx Packets: 696

﻿Usage: 2

anyone could give a hand with this, because i know hoiw to make a static route in a cisco device

ip route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0 ip next hop / outgoing interface / AD

but in this case i have this problem with this device...please help

Comment: Check the following post. While he mentions another router it actually isn't part of the answer/requirement. http://serverfault.com/questions/452027/sonicwall-routing-between-multiple-subnets-on-multiple-interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Network Configuration menu, did you created the rule there ?

I show a printscreen from a device I have, you see object class I done, red-lan & blue-lan. It's different subnet that for my case use the default route 0.0.0.0 to get out.

[image]

Comment: Hello yagmoth555 the routing entries are create in the network>routing section, because i can reach the other firewall subnet from LAN A, and the traffic return from the dedicated link from the LAN B, i can reach the servers with icmp, with windows remote desktop and i can bring back up with acronis, but when i tried to reach the LAN b from the LAN B where are the servers i can not, and viewing the firewall rules i found the statistics, for that i believe there is something with the firewall that i can not find the trick. can  you help?

Comment: hello yagmoth555, both routing entries are create in the network>routing section, and because i can reach with ICMP, RDP and Acronis from LAN A  to LAN b from where are the servers, but in the other hand i can not reach the LAN B from LAN A i thinks there is someting with the firewall rules that i being missing, can you help me?

Comment: lan-b to lan-b server fail as I see it ?